# Multiple Section In Recyclerview (Need more than 3 Section)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need To Add 4 Section In Recyclerview - Each one Contain Header And Footer. 
I have Tried This GitHub Library -

https://github.com/afollestad/sectioned-recyclerview

Issue - It Only Provides Only Two Section.
Is there anyway or Library Where I can Implement More Section. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Wait will give you the code for that........

Comment: Waiting for Your Reply.

Comment: Try this one instead: https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter